# Finding specific character in given string

Tags: infopath2010

I am trying to have a rule which can check if there is any 0 in given string. For example, My string format can be like, 34393903432 or any combination . I should be able to check if there is any 0. I tried using contains function but doesn't work. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The contains function should work for this.

i.e contains(field1, "city")

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/infopath-help/functions-in-infopath-HP001155281.aspx

Can you add how you used the contains function?